# Checking if a matrix field with entries has more than one entry

Tags: matrix, conditional, field, entries-field

In my HTML-prototype I have two ways of showing a module of employees. One version shows one employee, and the other shows two.

To build this in Craft I have setup a Matrix field (with a handle named 'contactMatrix'). It contains a headline, some text and an entry field to pick employees (with a limit of two).

To output this in my front end I need a way to check if the user has picked one or two employees. Something like:

if one employee within the matrix field is chosen
*do this html*
else
if two employees within the matrix field is chosen
*do this slightly different html*
end if

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the code below should work. This code assumes you are on a single entry page or within a loop and your entry is available to you with the `entry` variable. You may need to adjust the `block.type` name and `block.employees` entries field name to match your proper handles. I've added comments inline to clarify each step:

```
{# Loop through your Matrix Field #}
{% for block in entry.contactMatrix %}

    {# Check to see which type of block you have.  You only want to check for the employees entry field if you are within the contact block #}
    {% if block.type == 'contact' %}

        {# See if your employees entries field has more than 1 entry #}
        {% if block.employees|length > 1 %}

          {# Output HTML for blocks with multiple employees #}

        {% else %}

          {# Output HTML for blocks with zero or one employee #}

        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That `else` is `{# Output HTML for blocks with ZERO OR one employee #}`

Comment: @Oyvind could you please accept / update helpful answers to your questions?